# Difference between functionName:()=>void; and functionName():void; in an interface

Tags: typescript

The title says it all. I don't understand the specific effects of choosing the first or the second way to declare the signature of a function

```
 interface Human {
  firstName : string;
  age: number;

  greet:()=> void;
}
```

and

```
interface Human {
  firstName : string;
  age: number;

  greet():void;
}
```

I hope you can clarify this for me.

Thanks guys

Comment: @KarstenGabriel that question has nothing in common with this one. It's about different ways of creating functions in JS (and also applies to TS). However, this one is about type declarations in TS which is *not* the same as creating the functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One is a field that happens to be a function, the other is a method. This might not seem like a big deal at first (for interfaces), and in most cases it is not. There is however a subtle difference between the two, namely variance.

Parameters for function signatures are contra-variant, while for methods parameters they are bi-varaint. This comes into play when checking compatibility between types and when implementing the interface.

Now in  your case since you don't actually have any parameters, this has no impact, but it you were to have a parameter, this can become importat:

```
{
    interface Human {
        greet: (p: string | null) => void;
    }
    class HumanImpl implements Human {
        greet(p: string) { // Error Types of parameters 'p' and 'p' are incompatible.

        }
    }
}
{
    interface Human {
        greet(p: string | null): void;
    }
    class HumanImpl implements Human {
        greet(p: string) { // This is fine for methods
            return "Hi" + p.toUpperCase() // p is never null,  right?
        }
    }
    let h: Human = new HumanImpl();
    h.greet(null) // wops, runtime error on type cheched code

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/N4KABBYJYHYC4FMBOAzAhgYwWAEgVwFs0YxRJywBzJBBOALjAAoAHRgZziVkrAB8wMPABthASjABeAHxgAbgHsoAEwDc4SAF8NEDMLTt2uQsQCSBFsOgXhCAgnhH8REmQoRqtOKw5ceE4DAAeiCwAFEkJAUkMAAVAE8WBCMFFDAWNCQ0e0QkIwByFnywYmUwQuLM7FgMBQs0OCgAI1sAOhAdCm1ybW03CFhc9CxjF1JO8k86HzBObhheASFRMUZFFXUezr0DJxMYc0trSzsHOD2x-oop7zZZvwWA4NDYgAsoIw+wFFhsFGiwDlXgplOwJu4wDQ4HgkCQAEQ4KBwsAAanSrTgCgAqiwkkgAMIGBBMCQhdLQIwwBByZCCETCAA0EG4lFecAA-OCIN0tJ1bHAwK9GM5iFJBAgAO6jMw2EmbSCvVo3JjLcTPMAShQsdhMpB4eBQexgZBRGIKEhwRLYDCvBA2hBlWrKBAdTRAA)

For more about variance see my [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EInunOVRsUU)

The reason for this loophole is that with strict variance for methods, most types (and importantly `Array`) would become invariant as explained in this [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654)

Note: For classes there is an added discussion as to if the function is on the instance or the prototype, but this does not come into play for interfaces.

Comment: I found your [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMIoXT80NDXzH2COsDtxNgg) yesterday. Keep up the good work!

Comment: @spender I think I just found my topic for today or tomorrow for a short video :)

Comment: By the way, do we agree that the effects are the same when declaring a typealias ?

Comment: @MaxHimes You mean replace type with interface ? Then yes. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/N4KABBYC4J4A4FMwAkCuBbAhgOzAXjFEmLAHMAnBBKALjAAo46BnKcgS21LAB8xtUAG0EBKfAD4wANwD27ACYBucJAC+KiAGNBmZsxQYcASXRxBYdqcEJ0CbFH1osuIiQgUqURizadSY4DAAeiCwAFFychlyMAAVeAR9GQAzMDhMckxbKARyfQByOHywHHkwQuKMpE5NGVNMKHYAI2sAOhANEnVidXVXCFhEA2d8Qk7iD2pvMFYOLl5+IVE6WQVlHs7tXUdDbBMzCysbOwdhnDG3d0opphnfLgDg0NiAC3Z9d7BkziRk6LBsi8ZPJmONLpQoKhyLgAETIdgwsAAajSrSgMgAqnBEOQAMK6BD0MQhNIWfTYBBSXKLYQAGggHFILygAH4wRBumpOtYoGAXnQnOcCBSAO5nPZWInrSAvVqTLwCYTE0IimRwZj08ioeyWJC5KIxGS4QZITQvBBmhBlWryBAdVRAA

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes!

Comment: Should I use by default : greet: (p: string | null) => void;
To avoid runtime errors and get compilation errors ?

Comment: @MaxHimes If you want max safety for your interfaces function signatures are better, but be advised, they can cause type compatibility headaches.